# c3.js How to get the name types of the series of a chart?

Tags: c3.js

for example, chart.data.names(), return array with name series ('data1','data2'...).
 I need something like chart.data.types(), to return array 'data1':'bar','data2':'line', because I need to act on the series according to the type, and the series are loaded dynamically with chart.load(), and chart.unload().
 The chart 'remember' the type active when load, and if unload and load later, not affected transform intermediate.
for example:
chart generate data1, type line 
chart load data2
chart load data3
chart load data4
chart transform bar
chart unload data3
chart transform line
chart load data3 // remains in type bar

Comment: where is your sample data, your question is unclear

Comment: " and if unload and load later, not affected transform intermediate."  <-- this part isn't too clear to me.  I think with a couple edits concerning clarity (and maybe some code?) you question will get more responses.

Answer (score 0):

There is an undocumented function:

```
chart.internal.config.data_types
```

But.... it doesn't return series that use the default type (the line chart) if you haven't set that type explicitly

e.g. data1, data2 with types { data1: "bar" } would only return a type for data1